# pecl install imagick fails on M1 MacBook with PHP 8.0

Tags: php, macos, imagick, pecl, apple-m1

**UPDATE**

It seems this issue is related to the PECL itself:

https://github.com/Imagick/imagick/issues/331

---

I'm unable to run the build process for `pecl install imagick` and not get any information from the error logs. I use a Mac (OS 11.2.1) with the latest Apple M1 processor. The library is used in combination with PHP 8.0.2

Before I started the build process, I installed the following brew packages:

**required libraries**

```
brew install pkg-config
brew install imagemagick
```

**build command**

```
pecl install imagick
```

**build process log**

```
creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: patching config.h.in
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/sh /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootgEqg8P/imagick-3.4.4/libtool --mode=compile cc -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootgEqg8P/imagick-3.4.4/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootgEqg8P/imagick-3.4.4/main -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.2/include/php -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.2/include/php/main -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.2/include/php/TSRM -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.2/include/php/Zend -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.2/include/php/ext -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.2/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.11-0/include/ImageMagick-7  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.11-0/include/ImageMagick-7 -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c -o imagick_file.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootgEqg8P/imagick-3.4.4/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootgEqg8P/imagick-3.4.4/main -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.2/include/php -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.2/include/php/main -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.2/include/php/TSRM -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.2/include/php/Zend -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.2/include/php/ext -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.2/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.11-0/include/ImageMagick-7 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.11-0/include/ImageMagick-7 -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/imagick_file.o
In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:22:
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick_file.h:61:108: error: expected ')'
zend_bool php_imagick_file_init(struct php_imagick_file_t *file, const char *filename, size_t filename_len TSRMLS_DC);
                                                                                                           ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick_file.h:61:32: note: to match this '('
zend_bool php_imagick_file_init(struct php_imagick_file_t *file, const char *filename, size_t filename_len TSRMLS_DC);
                               ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick_file.h:65:54: error: expected ')'
int php_imagick_safe_mode_check(const char *filename TSRMLS_DC);
                                                     ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick_file.h:65:32: note: to match this '('
int php_imagick_safe_mode_check(const char *filename TSRMLS_DC);
                               ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick_file.h:68:134: error: expected ')'
php_imagick_rw_result_t php_imagick_read_file(php_imagick_object *intern, struct php_imagick_file_t *file, ImagickOperationType type TSRMLS_DC);
                                                                                                                                     ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick_file.h:68:46: note: to match this '('
php_imagick_rw_result_t php_imagick_read_file(php_imagick_object *intern, struct php_imagick_file_t *file, ImagickOperationType type TSRMLS_DC);
                                             ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick_file.h:71:153: error: expected ')'
php_imagick_rw_result_t php_imagick_write_file(php_imagick_object *intern, struct php_imagick_file_t *file, ImagickOperationType type, zend_bool adjoin TSRMLS_DC);
                                                                                                                                                        ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick_file.h:71:47: note: to match this '('
php_imagick_rw_result_t php_imagick_write_file(php_imagick_object *intern, struct php_imagick_file_t *file, ImagickOperationType type, zend_bool adjoin TSRMLS_DC);
                                              ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick_file.h:74:112: error: expected ')'
zend_bool php_imagick_stream_handler(php_imagick_object *intern, php_stream *stream, ImagickOperationType type TSRMLS_DC);
                                                                                                               ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick_file.h:74:37: note: to match this '('
zend_bool php_imagick_stream_handler(php_imagick_object *intern, php_stream *stream, ImagickOperationType type TSRMLS_DC);
                                    ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:81:51: error: expected ')'
zend_bool php_imagick_is_url(const char *filename TSRMLS_DC)
                                                  ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:81:29: note: to match this '('
zend_bool php_imagick_is_url(const char *filename TSRMLS_DC)
                            ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:85:90: error: expected ')'
        if (php_stream_locate_url_wrapper(filename, &path_for_open, STREAM_LOCATE_WRAPPERS_ONLY TSRMLS_CC)) {
                                                                                                ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:85:35: note: to match this '('
        if (php_stream_locate_url_wrapper(filename, &path_for_open, STREAM_LOCATE_WRAPPERS_ONLY TSRMLS_CC)) {
                                         ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:91:108: error: expected ')'
zend_bool php_imagick_file_init(struct php_imagick_file_t *file, const char *filename, size_t filename_len TSRMLS_DC)
                                                                                                           ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:91:32: note: to match this '('
zend_bool php_imagick_file_init(struct php_imagick_file_t *file, const char *filename, size_t filename_len TSRMLS_DC)
                               ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:123:40: error: expected ')'
                else if (php_imagick_is_url(filename TSRMLS_CC)) {
                                                     ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:123:30: note: to match this '('
                else if (php_imagick_is_url(filename TSRMLS_CC)) {
                                           ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:142:53: error: expected ')'
        file->absolute_path = expand_filepath(buffer, NULL TSRMLS_CC);
                                                           ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:142:39: note: to match this '('
        file->absolute_path = expand_filepath(buffer, NULL TSRMLS_CC);
                                             ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:160:133: error: expected ')'
int php_imagick_read_image_using_imagemagick(php_imagick_object *intern, struct php_imagick_file_t *file, ImagickOperationType type TSRMLS_DC)
                                                                                                                                    ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:160:45: note: to match this '('
int php_imagick_read_image_using_imagemagick(php_imagick_object *intern, struct php_imagick_file_t *file, ImagickOperationType type TSRMLS_DC)
                                            ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:201:133: error: expected ')'
int php_imagick_read_image_using_php_streams(php_imagick_object *intern, struct php_imagick_file_t *file, ImagickOperationType type TSRMLS_DC)
                                                                                                                                    ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:201:45: note: to match this '('
int php_imagick_read_image_using_php_streams(php_imagick_object *intern, struct php_imagick_file_t *file, ImagickOperationType type TSRMLS_DC)
                                            ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:207:2: error: expected ')'
        IMAGICK_SET_ERROR_HANDLING_THROW;
        ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:28:133: note: expanded from macro 'IMAGICK_SET_ERROR_HANDLING_THROW'
#  define IMAGICK_SET_ERROR_HANDLING_THROW zend_replace_error_handling(EH_THROW, php_imagick_exception_class_entry, &error_handling TSRMLS_CC)
                                                                                                                                    ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:207:2: note: to match this '('
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:28:71: note: expanded from macro 'IMAGICK_SET_ERROR_HANDLING_THROW'
#  define IMAGICK_SET_ERROR_HANDLING_THROW zend_replace_error_handling(EH_THROW, php_imagick_exception_class_entry, &error_handling TSRMLS_CC)
                                                                      ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:216:3: error: expected ')'
                IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING;
                ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:29:88: note: expanded from macro 'IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING'
#  define IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING   zend_restore_error_handling(&error_handling TSRMLS_CC)
                                                                                       ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:216:3: note: to match this '('
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:29:71: note: expanded from macro 'IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING'
#  define IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING   zend_restore_error_handling(&error_handling TSRMLS_CC)
                                                                      ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:224:3: error: expected ')'
                IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING;
                ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:29:88: note: expanded from macro 'IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING'
#  define IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING   zend_restore_error_handling(&error_handling TSRMLS_CC)
                                                                                       ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:224:3: note: to match this '('
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:29:71: note: expanded from macro 'IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING'
#  define IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING   zend_restore_error_handling(&error_handling TSRMLS_CC)
                                                                      ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:228:2: error: expected ')'
        IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING;
        ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:29:88: note: expanded from macro 'IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING'
#  define IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING   zend_restore_error_handling(&error_handling TSRMLS_CC)
                                                                                       ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:228:2: note: to match this '('
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:29:71: note: expanded from macro 'IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING'
#  define IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING   zend_restore_error_handling(&error_handling TSRMLS_CC)
                                                                      ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:255:54: error: expected ')'
int php_imagick_safe_mode_check(const char *filename TSRMLS_DC)
                                                     ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:255:32: note: to match this '('
int php_imagick_safe_mode_check(const char *filename TSRMLS_DC)
                               ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:262:64: error: expected ')'
        if (PG(open_basedir) && php_check_open_basedir_ex(filename, 0 TSRMLS_CC)) {
                                                                      ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:262:51: note: to match this '('
        if (PG(open_basedir) && php_check_open_basedir_ex(filename, 0 TSRMLS_CC)) {
                                                         ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:269:134: error: expected ')'
php_imagick_rw_result_t php_imagick_read_file(php_imagick_object *intern, struct php_imagick_file_t *file, ImagickOperationType type TSRMLS_DC)
                                                                                                                                     ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:269:46: note: to match this '('
php_imagick_rw_result_t php_imagick_read_file(php_imagick_object *intern, struct php_imagick_file_t *file, ImagickOperationType type TSRMLS_DC)
                                             ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [imagick_file.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Comment: As you can see in the issue tracker of Imagick, they need to work on this. There's nothing you can do about this - unless you want to help resolve this through a pull request :)

Answer (score 7):

You need install imagick from git

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Imagick/imagick

$ cd imagick

$ phpize && ./configure

$ make

$ make test

$ make install
```

After install edit your php.ini and add the line `extension="imagick.so"`.

Restart apache and create a index.php with phpinfo() for check if module imagick ok.

```
$ echo "<?php phpinfo();" > /your-web-patch/index.php
```

Comment: This is a pretty good advice and helps compiling the imagick extension on Mac M1.

Comment: I get the following error running make:
`ld: in '/usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.0.dylib', building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64`
Any idea?

Comment: I get the following error on the last step `make install`: `mkdir: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.2.1_1/pecl: File exists` `mkdir: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.2.1_1/pecl: No such file or directory` `make: *** [install-modules] Error 1` Any idea? **solved** I followed [these steps](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/using-imagick-with-valet?page=1&replyId=540739)

Comment: You helped me! But after "make install" I moved this folder to homebrew directory and linked it in php.ini as extension="/opt/homebrew/etc/imagick/modules/imagick.so" but it can be any path also in Downloads.

Answer (score 3):

There is no release of imagick for PHP 8 yet. They say master works, but that may or may not help you. Note, this is unrelated to Apple Silicon—it doesn't work on Intel, neither.

Comment: How about now in 2023?